# What are the R based web interfaces? What are their features?

Tags: r, rstudio

What are the features of R based Web Consoles? What are their advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: I am trying to delete this question. How do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's easy:

- [Rweb](http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/) is pretty old, and a basic webinterface.  The R FAQ lists more such webapps in its Section 4 on [R and Web interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces).

  Webapps such as Rweb are for external third-parties, and mostly involve pre-canned code.
- [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org) is new (and especially if running in web-mode on a server) a phenomenal new-school 'application as a webservice'. If running that way, or as a local app, it provides an IDE for R. That is different from a webapp.

  IDEs such as Rstudio are for developers writing code. Theses IDEs are not facing unknown anonymous users.